# How to sort an array of objects by calculated value

Tags: arrays, sorting, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

Hello I'm trying to sort an array of objects by value, trought a function that calculates the average of the values in that objects property, which is an array of integers, then sorts it in decreasing order.

```
// SORT BY SCORE BY MOST SCORED
function sortByScoreDown() {
    arrayLivros.sort((a, b) => fullscoreForSort(b._scores) - fullscoreForSort(a._scores));
}

// CALCULATE FULLSCORE
function fullscoreForSort(givenScores) {
    let score = 0;
    let total = givenScores.length - 1; // -1 BECAUSE BOOK._SCORES STARTS WITH AN ARRAY WITH 0 AS FIRST VALUE FOR SIMPLIFICATION
    if (total != 0) {
        let summedScore = givenScores.reduce((sum, add) => sum + add);
        let score = summedScore / total;   
    }
    return score;
}

// VALUES
newBook1 = {_title: book1,
            _scores: [0,100,50]}
newBook2 = {_title: book2,
            _scores: [0,100,100]}
newBook3 = {_title: book3,
            _scores: [0,50,50]}
newBook4 = {_title: book3,
            _scores: [0,30,30]}

arrayBooks = [newBook1, newBook2, newBook3, newBook4];


// EXCPECTED RETURN
arrayBooks = [newBook2, newBook1, newBook3, newBook4];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the expected output?

Comment: Doesn't outup any error, it just doesn't sort it correctly.

Comment: Can you please add the expected and the real result.

Comment: Added expected result, but i dont really understand what it is doing in my code.

Comment: Ok i fixed it the problem was dividing by zero if the newBook._scores add only the value 0, because total would be 0 and you get it. Thanks everyone.